# duplicate value store in DropDownList2 when DropDownList1 value selected

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
if(!IsPostBack)
   {
     DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Category"));
     SqlDataReader dr = DAL.ExecuteReaderDemo("select * from addcategory");
  while (dr.HasRows)
      {
        dr.Read();
 DropDownList1.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem(dr[1].ToString(), dr[0].ToString()));
       }
         dr.Close();
            }
        }
```

DropDownList1 not showing duplicate value but when i select dropdownlist2 it's showing duplicate value. i don't understand which code add in `if(!IsPostBack)`.

Comment: have you put up debug point , and try to find out code hits second time or not , `!IsPostBak` not allow to hit back but you can try by putting break point there

Comment: where is the code of DropDownList2 binding?

Comment: added answer, can you have try , and let me know if there is any issuer

Comment: use DropDownList1.Items.Clear() before binding it with postback event from other drop down.

Comment: there ? you should reply on comments to get better answer

Comment: @iGod thnk u DropDownList1.Items.Clear() works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply put

```
    if(!IsPostBack)
   {
     DropDownList1.Items.Clear()
     DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Category"));
     SqlDataReader dr = DAL.ExecuteReaderDemo("select * from addcategory");
  while (dr.HasRows)
      {
        dr.Read();
 DropDownList1.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem(dr[1].ToString(),dr[0].ToString()));
       }
         dr.Close();
 }
```

Comment: I try this. But i have 2 DropDownList i got duplicate value in DropDownList2 . My problem is solve by DropDownList2.Items.Clear()

Comment: ok when you  bind dropdown1 and dropdown2 please clear previous value

Answer (score 0):

use DropDownList1.Items.Clear() before binding it with postback event from other drop down.